# How to sum only few lines using bash from a file

Tags: bash, shell

How to sum only few lines from a file using bash

my file

```
10
20
30
40
```

I need to add only 10+30 using bash and output them to a variable
I have the code but its lengthy and doesnt look good

my code

```
a=$(sed -n '1p' file1)
b=$(sed -n '3p' file1)
total=`expr $a + $b`
echo $total
```

Is there any better way of doing it

Comment: You should remove one of your tags. Bash and `[shell]` (e.g. POSIX shell) are quite different in the built-in features offered. A Bash solution will not necessarily work for POSIX shell -- though the reverse should. The benefit to using shell built-in features is you avoid spawning additional subshells necessary for calling utilities like `sed` or `awk`. However, if you need a POSIX shell solution, then you won't have built-ins like `mapfile` (`readarray`) available. If you use only a utility like `sed` or `awk` in a single call, then you avoid the subshell concern.

Comment: Answered both for bash and posix shell

Comment: If you already **know** in advance, that you want to add 10 and 30, why reading the file? If you do not know this in advance, what is the rule which lines of the file contain the numbers to be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) (`POSIX`), let's **[KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)**:

:

```
awk 'NR==1{a=$1} NR==3{b=$1;exit}END{print a + b}' file1
40
```

With [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
read a b < <(sed -n '1p;3p' file1 | paste -sd' ' -)
echo $((a + b))
40
```

`((...))` and `$((...))` are arithmetic commands, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for "let", if side effects (assignments) are needed.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

---

Process Substitution `>(command ...)` or `<(...)` is replaced by a temporary filename. Writing or reading that file causes bytes to get piped to the command inside. Often used in combination with file redirection: `cmd1 2> >(cmd2)`.
See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Answer (score 3):

Bash provides `mapfile` (synonymous with `readarray`) that will read the lines of `myfile.txt` into an indexed array. Then simply sum the elements you want, either manually providing the indexes, or within a loop, for example summing odd or even values. In your case you could do:

```bash
mapfile -t arr < myfile.txt
sum=$((${arr[0]}+${arr[2]}))
echo $sum
```

**Use/Output**

With your data in `myfile.txt` you would have:

```
$ mapfile -t arr < myfile.txt; sum=$((${arr[0]}+${arr[2]})); echo $sum
40
```

Comment: No need an array

Comment: Agreed, using an array is just a convenient option.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR==1{x=$0} NR==3{print x+$0; exit}' file
40
```

That script exits once the 2nd target line is read for efficiency vs continuing to read the rest of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the definition of 'better' is that you mean. But 'different' is as follows:

For sum of odd numbered line values:

`awk 'BEGIN{t=0}{if (NR%2 == 1) t+=$1;}END{print t}' file1`

For even numbered lines:

`awk 'BEGIN{t=0}{if (NR%2 == 0) t+=$1;}END{print t}' file1`

For particular lines (e.g 1, 4, 6):

`awk 'BEGIN{t=0}{if (NR == 1 || NR == 4 || NR == 6) t+=$1;}END{print t}' file1`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method with `sed` and `bc`:

```
sed 'N;N;s/\n.*\n/+/;q' file | bc
```